# How to detect interface orientation when in popover?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I'm in a `UIViewController` class that is currently being presented as a popover, how do I detect what orientation I'm in?

I've tried the usual `self.interfaceOrientation` but this always returns `Portrait` even when the device is in landscape.  What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation
```

or  you could work with notifications after an orientation change

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` worked perfectly!  Any idea why this would work in a popover but `self.interfaceOrientation` would not?

Answer (score 3):

This should give you what you need:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

You need to call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

before this property starts to produce the correct values.